# Machine power on doesn't take place unless a power cable is connected

Tags: macbook-pro

I have a macbook air 13" late 2015. When I try to power it on a sound comes from the fan though the computer doesn't boot up. It does boot though if it's plugged in. Sometimes when I'm using the computer it randomly shuts off. I've tried to do a SMC reset once, but the issue still remains the same. What is a solution to this problem?

Comment: Have you run Apple Hardware Test? Sounds like a battery thing to me.

Comment: Indeed, likely a battery issue. An Apple store might diagnose the issue for free for you.